# Can't bind to 'leafletOptions' since it isn't a known property of 'div'

Tags: typescript, ngx-leaflet

I know this is an issue that comes up here often and is fixed by fixing import statements. I currently have

```
import { LeafletModule } from 'node_modules/@asymmetrik/ngx-leaflet';
import * as L from 'leaflet';
import { } from '@types/leaflet';
```

I am referencing options and as such:

```
options = {
    layers: [
        this.googleHybrid
    ],
    zoom: 1.49,
    zoomSnap: 0,
    center: L.latLng([180, -180])}
```

I feel like I am running into this issue because of importing everything from leaflet as L. Any thoughts?

Edit: I should also add that this is only coming up in testing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it. I didn't add the proper imports to my test configuration file for the parent component. All good now!

Comment: Can you add the part you were missing in the test ? I'm running into the same problem as well

Answer (score 6):

This happens when Angular.io hasn't properly loaded the LeafletModule into your application. Usually, you'd do the following:

First, Import `LeafletModule` into your application module:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { LeafletModule } from '@asymmetrik/ngx-leaflet';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    LeafletModule.forRoot()
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

And then, if you are using ngx-leaflet in a sub module of the application module, you need to import it into that one too:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { LeafletModule } from '@asymmetrik/ngx-leaflet';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
  ],
  imports: [
    LeafletModule
  ],
  providers: []
})
export class MyModule { }
```

There's [a tutorial](https://www.asymmetrik.com/ngx-leaflet-tutorial-angular-cli/) that address how to get up and running with Angular CLI, but it doesn't address the situation where you have sub modules of the application module using ngx-leaflet.

A couple other notes:

- It would be unusual for you to need to provide the path into node_modules when you import `LeafletModule`. Most build pipelines will dereference packages automatically.
- The same goes for the `@types/leaflet` import. Most build pipelines will automatically pull in type information if needed.
- It's perfectly valid to do `import * as L from 'leaflet';` You can also import specific items as needed e.g., `import Map from {leaflet};`

Comment: I just confirmed that I did all of that and I am still getting the error for some reason. I appreciate the notes as they do help as well.

Comment: I should also bring up the fact that this is only coming up in testing. Just edited my post.

Comment: In `ngx-leaflet@7`, the `forRoot()` has been removed. Also ensure that modules are configured correctly, I made the error of trying to have the modules in a different folder to app.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem with the tests,
but when I added:

```
imports: [
  LeafletModule,
  LeafletMarkerClusterModule
]
```

the problem disappeared.

Answer (score 1):

This problem occurs when your map is used in a custom module.

I suggest you try to import your custom module into the application module.

[image: example image]

Answer (score 0):

If it helps anyone I got this when I didn't put my new `MapComponent` into the `declarations` in `app.module.ts` (with ngx-leaflet otherwise imported correctly).